# unlink function not working on files over 1mb

Tags: php, file, unlink

Does anyone know why the unlink function would be working with a file under 1mb but fails with one above 1mb? Is there a setting in the php.ini I need to change?

Cheers

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: are you sure it's because it's over 1 mb? it doesn't sounds to me such a thing, try to catch the error message and checking the file's ownership

Comment: I'm unlinking 2GB files and is working fine :]] Post your logs, PHP version, server OS and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Was not the unlink function in the end was the memory_limit in php.ini having an effect on the imagecreatefromjpeg function. Limit increased and problem solved.